# How to get all preceding nodes regardless of the current position

Tags: xslt, nodes

Structure of my XML

```
<root>
    <Q id="a">1</Q>
    <Q id="b">2</Q>
    <Q id="c">3</Q>
      <x> 
          <Q id="d">3.1</Q> 
          <Q id="e">3.2</Q>
          <Q id="f">3.3</Q>
      </x>
    <Q id="g">4</Q>
    <Q id="h">5</Q>
</root>
```

This is my XPath expression:

```
//Q[@id=$CurrentQid]/preceding::Q
```

I'm trying to get list of preceding Q nodes regardless of the current position (I'm passing current position as a parameter to my xslt) 
when I am on `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"g"`, `"h"` nodes it  returns me the correct list of preceding nodes. But when I am on `"d"`, `"e"`, `"f"` it does not working right.

For example: when my current node is `"g"` it returns,

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

but when my current node is `"f"` it returns only

```
d,e,f
```

although I expect it to be

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

If any one can find a solution that would be very good.

Thank you.

Comment: You are sure this happens with this example xml? It should not and does not for me.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add your `XSL` please?

Comment: Still I do not see what happen. Looks like  preceding-sibling instead of  preceding is executed somehow. What xslt / xpaht processor do you use?

Comment: @hr_117: I would have said the same thing, except that if the XPath expression was using `preceding-sibling::`, the result from context node `g` would not have included d,e,f as it did.

Comment: Yes you are right, so this is really strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
($yourNode/preceding::Q | $yourNode/ancestor::Q)/@id
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vQg" select="(//Q[@id='g'])[1]"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vQf" select="(//Q[@id='f'])[1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  "Preceding" $vQg:

  <xsl:for-each select=
  "($vQg/preceding::Q | $vQg/ancestor::Q)/@id">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
=====================

  "Preceding" $vQf:

  <xsl:for-each select=
  "($vQf/preceding::Q | $vQf/ancestor::Q)/@id">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <Q id="a">1</Q>
    <Q id="b">2</Q>
    <Q id="c">3</Q>
      <x>
          <Q id="d">3.1</Q>
          <Q id="e">3.2</Q>
          <Q id="f">3.3</Q>
      </x>
    <Q id="g">4</Q>
    <Q id="h">5</Q>
</root>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated twice (for the two `Q` elements from your question) and the string values of the results are output separated with space**:

```
  "Preceding" $vQg:

  a b c d e f 
=====================

  "Preceding" $vQf:

  a b c d e
```

**Explanation**:

The `preceding::` axis doesn't select all preceding nodes in document order -- to do this one needs also to use the `ancestor::` axis.

**From the [W3C XPath 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes)**:

> "• *the preceding axis contains all nodes in the same document as the
>   context node that are before the context node in document order,
>   excluding any ancestors and excluding attribute nodes and namespace
>   nodes*"

Comment: This is a good explanation for preceding::. But there is no Q-ancestor to any Q in the xml example. Therefore preceding:: should have the same result. Or what do I miss here?

Comment: @hr_117, Oh, I was misled by the indentation in the question. Maybe the OP didn't provide the real document (judging from the indentation) and his problem was due exactly to not taking into account the `ancestor::` axis.

Comment: Thank you Dimitre> I managed to get my expected result using following xPath expression by refering to your answer.  ---------------------------------------------------------------------- ($yourNode//Q[@id]/preceding::Q | $yourNode//Q[@id]/ancestor::Q)